# UI-Router - query parameter not allowing array with single item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have an application using UI-Router. There is a `Widgets` state with one query parameter that accepts an array of widgets:

```
const widgetsState = { name: "widgets", url: "/widgets?{widgets:string[]}", component: Widgets, params: {
  widgets: {
    isArray: true,
    value: [],
  }
} };
```

Routing to this state works with an empty array or an array with multiple items, but fails when given an array of just one item:

```
<a uiSref="widgets" [uiParams]="{ widgets: [] }">Empty array - works fine</a>
<a uiSref="widgets" [uiParams]="{ widgets: ['foo'] }">Single item - throws error!</a>
<a uiSref="widgets" [uiParams]="{ widgets: ['foo','bar'] }">Multiple items - works fine</a>
```

When routing with just a single item in the array, I get this error:

> This transition is invalid, detail: The following parameter values are not valid for state 'widgets': [widgets:"foo"]))

**How can I get UI-Router to allow an array containing a single item to be passed in as a parameter?**

This [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/uirouter-angular-hello-world-nwxubm) shows a minimal reproduction of the error.

I've noticed that if I remove the parameter from the url, it will properly handle arrays of single items. However I need to retain the ability to deep-link with these parameters, so that's not an option for my application.

Comment: This is an issue from`UI-Router`, the unit test case are failing for single array element in there source code. Its a Transition issue which is considering the `['foo'] as 'foo'`. Please raise a ticket. But for your issue try some some hacky way if u need quick fix.

Comment: FYI, I cross-posted this question to the [UI-Router/Angular Github page](https://github.com/ui-router/angular/issues/829).

Comment: @NavKumarV I haven't pulled down UI-Router and built it locally, but the badge on GitHub claims the build is passing. Can you elaborate? I'd also call this a bug, except that it seems like such a normal situation that the problem must be me (but I don't see how.)

Comment: The existing build is passing with `multiple array` element scenario, But I took a local build and added the `single array` scenario, which resulted the test cases to fail. I am positive that it is not an problem that might be caused by you.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` in front of `string[]` inside `widgetsState` **is redundant**. Please read the *ui-router* documents carefully. In your case, the page [Interface ParamDeclaration](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.20/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html) describes how to configure parameters. This is your [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/uirouter-angular-hello-world-abe9rr) with no error.

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper What are you looking for? This is not a bug in ui-router. You've misused it.

Comment: This is the solution and yes, the documentation says in case of at least two parameters of same name: "If you specified a type for the parameter, the value will be treated as an array of the specified ParamType."

Comment: I'm looking to be able to receive an array with one item. This answer doesn't do that, instead it yields the single object by itself.

Comment: You just need to change your `isArray` to be `array` in your param definition. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/uirouter-angular-hello-world-qmiztz?file=src/main.ts for an updated stack blitz

Comment: @DanHooper that was exactly my problem! You should post that as an answer.